# initialize static array of objects c++

Tags: c++, static, initialization

How do I declare an array of "Database" objects (no dynamic memory) for the following class?

```
class DataBase
{
 public: 
      DataBase(int code);
 private:
      Database();
      Database(const Database &);
      Database &operator=(const Database &);
 };
```

Comment: Please add what you have already tried to solve your problem to your question so that ppl can more easily help you. It is also always worth checking out the help center of stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The code will not compile unless we _also_ fix the typos in the excerpt provided.

Comment: Arda - I've edited the code to add the semicolon at the end of the class

Answer (score 5):

In C++17 and beyond, either like this:

```
Database a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Or with explicit constructors:

```
Database a[] = { Database(1), Database(2), Database(3) };
```

Pre-C++17, you could try something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

std::aligned_storage<3 * sizeof(DataBase), alignof(DataBase)>::type db_storage;
DataBase* db_ptr = reinterpret_cast<DataBase*>(&db_storage);

new (db_ptr + 0) DataBase(1);
new (db_ptr + 1) DataBase(2);
new (db_ptr + 2) DataBase(3);
```

Now you can use `db_ptr[0]` etc. This isn't entirely legitimate according to object lifetime and pointer arithmetic rules in C++11*, but It Works In Practice.

<sub>*) in the same way that std::vector cannot be implemented in C++11</sub>

Comment: Kerrek SB: Thanks for your response, but the copy constructor is private.  (So that solution didn't work)

Comment: @happyloman: As of C++17, there is no more copy. If you need a pre-C++17 answer, please say so (in which case it's not so easy).

Comment: @happyloman: Uninitialized storage and placement-new could be used pre-C++17.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this is for C++11. Sorry, I wasn't aware.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, pre-C++11 is a lot of work!